# two table join grid with distinct rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to build up a table like this:

**brief summary**
all columns from two tables.
ordered by DISTINCT day rows.
summing all due payments per day  `NAEDO` table
summing all successful/ Unsuccessful payments per day. `paysoft` table
Total payed for the day
Total outstanding for the day

[image]

Two tables are represented in this grid.

You have *payments due*`[NAEDO]` and you have *payments made/or failed*`[paysoft]`

There are multiple transactions every day and the grid is grouped by day with that days transactions summarized in that row.

**[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/889c5/3)** with the test data

I have tried a bit but Im struggling to JOIN the two tables.

```
SELECT 
    n.day,
    n.ACCOUNTS,
    ammount
FROM 
(
    SELECT  DISTINCT start_date, extract(day from start_date) as day, count(*)as ACCOUNTS, sum(amount)as ammount
    FROM NAEDO
    WHERE start_date >= '2014-08-13' AND start_date <= '2014-09-12'
    GROUP BY start_date
    ORDER BY start_date
) n
LEFT JOIN
(
    ????
) ps ON ps. = ps.custno
GROUP BY start_date, n.day, n.ACCOUNTS, ammount
ORDER BY start_date
```

So this query (without the second blank one) creates the rows and enters the amount due for the day and amount of accounts due for that day.
But trying to join the tables drops my `DISTINCT` selection

Please help or guide me to achieve the result.

Comment: Can you let us know what your trying on the ???? part, and what erorrs it is giving you. Also, what other values do you want to see from the join, basically whats your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your desired table correctly, you don't need the DISTINCT, and your join condition is wrong.  It looks like you're trying to join based on customer number, but you're not interested in that.  Instead, you need to join on a date (`n.start_date = ps.pay_date`).  I updated your code a bit to show how I think you want your join to work.

```
SELECT 
  n.day,
  n.ACCOUNTS,
  n.ammount,
  ps.amt_paid
FROM 
(
  SELECT  start_date, extract(day from start_date) as day, count(*)as ACCOUNTS, sum(amount)as ammount
  FROM NAEDO
  WHERE start_date >= '2014-07-13' AND start_date <= '2014-08-12'
  GROUP BY start_date
  ORDER BY start_date
) n
LEFT JOIN
(
  Select pay_date, sum(amount) as amt_paid
  From paysoft
  Group By pay_date
  Order By pay_date
) ps On n.start_date = ps.pay_date
Order By n.start_date
```

This doesn't factor in the logic to determine success percentage, and it also doesn't exclude failed payments from the `amt_paid`, but it should get you started.  Constructing your query this way will also cause problems calculating your number of accounts.  As written above, it only counts the number of accounts that had payments due on a specific day.  It can easily be changed to also include accounts that have made payments on the specific day, but then you're likely going to have some accounts counted twice.